# How to request Notification Permission in Jetpack Compose with a button?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-notifications, android-permissions

I am creating an app which is a Healthy Life application. In the app I want to send some notifications. I don't want to request permission like Accept for this app or accept for this time or deny. When app is opened a page will welcome users. This page will contain some information text about notification and below it there will be a button. When user click that button the permission will be accepted then the flow will go. There are some examples about requesting permission but as I said they have 3 options and contains some rationale if you deny for the first time etc. Briefly I want to request a notification permission with a button.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can start doing it with adding the dependency in `build.gradle(app-level)` file.

Jetpack Compose allows you to integrate the permission request flow seamlessly into your app.

```
implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.33.1-alpha")
```

Add the following permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

**Complete Code Here**

1. Define a state variable which keeps track of permission.
2. Check whether permission is given or not. if not ask for permission
3. Update UI based on permission.

---

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable

fun PermissionDemo() {

    val notificationPermission = rememberPermissionState(
        permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
    )
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column {
            Button(onClick = {
                if (!notificationPermission.status.isGranted) {
                    notificationPermission.launchPermissionRequest()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Given Already", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "Ask for permission")
            }
            Text(
                text = "Permission Status : ${notificationPermission.status.isGranted}",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 16.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always it triggers the toast message. Permission status is true even if I have never clicked on button as well.

Comment: You may be doing wrong because Button Click is not triggered automatically

Comment: I directly copied this code to my environment

Comment: I think there may be something wrong you are doing because it is tested and not possible that button click trigger automatically. share your complete code

Comment: Complete code is your code. Directly permission status coming as true.